# Why QGIS plugin builder doesn't make compile file

Tags: qgis

When i create plugin with Plugin builder, it doesn't make a compile file. How can I solve this problem? Although plugin works perfectly without compile file, I can't change the icon. I am using QGIS 3.32 Lima in Windows OS.